# How to get value from URL in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I had a url `http://localhost/tasty/index.php/admin/edititems?id=20`. I have to get the value `20`.

Comment: You should thoroughly review the online documentation:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$this->input->get('id', TRUE);
```

I'd recommend checking out the docs here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html