# How to get the URL paramters inside view using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Given this link:

> localhost/abc/review?coupon=bskgnlsdgkj

How do I get the coupon value inside view?
I tried `$_GET['coupon]`, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can check input parameter by using `$this->input->get('name_of_the_parameter');` 

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: And inside view you can do as follows.  `$ci =& get_instance(); $ci->input->get('coupon');` 
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html?highlight=get_instance#get_instance

Comment: please have a look at this docs: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: I think this question is duplicated with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042468/how-to-get-value-from-url-in-codeigniter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make CodeIgniter accept "query string" URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894250/how-to-make-codeigniter-accept-query-string-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$this->input->get('coupon');` to get the value of url parameter.
But, I suggest you to get the parameter value with `$this->input->get('coupon',TRUE);` to applying `XSS Security` directly.

For information can be found on this [link](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get).